# svg example in C/C++

Tags: c++, cairo

Can someone provide an example of how to load a .svg file and display it using C/C++ and any library? I'm wondering if you will use SDL, cairo, or what.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Pavel put it, [QtSvg](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtsvg.html) is the way to go i believe. It is easier to use but in our team we have faced performance issues with QtSvg especially on Linux. So we decided to directly parse the SVG file XML by hand and render it using Qt itself. This turned out to be much faster.

pseudocode:-

```
// Read the SVG file using XML parser (SAX)
void SvgReader::readFile()
{
  QFile file(<some svg filename>);
  if (!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text)) {
    qWarning("Cannot open file");
    return;
  }
  QString localName;
  QXmlStreamAttributes attributes;
  pXml = new QXmlStreamReader(&file);
  pXml->setNamespaceProcessing(false);
  while (!pXml->atEnd()) {
    switch (pXml->readNext()) {
        case QXmlStreamReader::StartElement:
          localName = pXml->name().toString();
          if (localName.compare(<some element path>) == 0) {
            attributes = pXml->attributes();
            QStringRef data  = attributes.value(<some attribute name>);
            // parse/use your data;
          }
        // similarly other case statements 
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Helltone,

check out http://cairographics.org/cairomm/

Might make things a little easier.

Answer (score 1):

[QtSvg](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/qtsvg.html) module might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

you may try [boost.svg_plot](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/wiki/LibrariesUnderConstruction#Boost.Plot)

Answer (score 1):

You can try [lunasvg](https://github.com/sammycage/lunasvg).

```cpp
#include <lunasvg/document.h>

int main()
{
    auto document = Document::loadFromFile("example.svg");
    auto bitmap = document->renderToBitmap();

    // do something useful with bitmap here.
}
```